# adding an icon to launcher without installing

Tags: android, android-launcher

I have certain apps which i want to show on launcher . When i click on it it should say app not installed . Is that possible ? I checked `AllAppsList.java` of ICS . I think we need to provide `ApplicationInfo` object for that . Is there any alternate ?

Answer (score 1):

Please correct me if I am wrong.

As far as I have understood it this is not possible unless **you control the launcher** itself. The launcher will add Apps that have the "android.intent.action.MAIN" and "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" in their manifest to the App drawer.

If there was a good way to add shortcuts to the launchers app drawer I am pretty sure the Ad Networks would use that to inject Ads there.

I guess your most viable option is to create shortcuts on the homescreen.

If you manage to find a solution for it though it would be awesome.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

It *ISN'T* possible. Unless I am misunderstanding the question. Perhaps make a seperate app altogether, with the same name and the same icon, but instead of any content in it, just link it to the market where the *full* app resides; Or something along those lines.